# How to loop through urls in python with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup

So I have this code where I extract the number of goals score from a certain website. I want to loop it through so that I can get the information for every player, for example: https://www.futbin.com/20/player/1, then https://www.futbin.com/20/player/2, then https://www.futbin.com/20/player/3 up to 5000. How would I go about that? Here is my code for how I get the goals information.

```
url = 'https://www.futbin.com/20/player/143/cristiano-ronaldo'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
googclose = soup.find_all(class_='ps4-pgp-data')
hi=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'ps4-pgp-data'})[4]
```

Comment: Accept the review sent (code needs to be formatted to be more readable)

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly then you can just create a list of player names or IDs like `['1','2','3']`, loop through the list using a variable `player_id` and create a `url` using `url = 'https://www.futbin.com/20/player/'+player_id` and rest of code remains the same in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_goals=[] 

for i in range(1,51):
    url = 'https://www.futbin.com/20/player/{}'.format(i)
    response = requests.get(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    goal=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'ps4-pgp-data'})[4].text.strip()
    all_goals.append(goal)
```